# find location using java app

Tags: java, spring, web, geolocation

how to find out the nearest place using Java (is there any third party lib which provides this support)

some thing like [this](http://www.indiaonapage.com/pincodelocator/)

my requirement is :

1. Enter the zip code or place name
2. select the categories like ATM, BANK, etc
3. list the nearest places.

Please suggest me which one to use to build the above.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google place search api to locate the places...

see documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)